# Python-docx and count tabs

Tags: python, ms-word, tabs, docx, python-docx

Can anyone help me count the number of tabs on a line in a docx file. I want to know the number of tabs to create a hierarchy e.g. one tab is 1), two tabs in is 1.1), three tabs in is 1.1.1) etc.

I am using Python 3's library python-docx.

```
from docx import *

document = Document('Sample.docx')

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:

  for run in paragraph.runs:

     #Count the number of tabs in a line of text
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `run` here a single line?

Comment: The text is one line but may have several runs

Comment: A tab character is represented in Word Open XML as `<w:tab>`, so possibly extract the descendant nodes in the paragraph of that type? I'd ignore the runs as they aren't relevant (even though a tab is "embedded" in a run).

Comment: Thanks Cindy. I extracted each paragraph into xml and used string.count(‘<w:tab/>’). That seems to work.